# Youtube api : Getting all the subscriptions of a user, then displaying them with their thumbnails and names

Tags: youtube-api

I'm working on a mobile application that will display all the subscriptions of a user (http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_subscriptions.html#Retrieving_subscriptions) and then then display each subscription in a list with their name and thumbnails (???)

Now as you can see i can do get the subscriptions and then to get thumbnail and title of each subscription i have to make a separate request (gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/subscriptions?v=2).

But if a user has 100 channels and then making 100 calls for each channel to display their thumbnail is not a good option.

Is there any other way to achieve the same result? any advises?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to list the channels the user has subscribed to, or the videos from these channels?

Comment: list the channels only, along with channel title and picture (which doesnt come in the retrieve subscription feed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a batch request might help? https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_batch_processing

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.